# How to get the users response to a command C# discord bot

Tags: c#, .net, bots, discord

I have been coding a discord bot for the past few days and I want to create jobs. For example, I have a Youtuber job and you need to enter in several things to complete it, the problem is I dont know how to get that message.

My command code is:

```
 [Command("jobsjoinyoutuber")]
    public async Task jobsjoinyoutuber()
    {
        var user = Context.User;
        var role = Context.Guild.Roles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Jobs: Youtuber");
        await (user as IGuildUser).AddRoleAsync(role);
    }

    [Command("workyoutuber")]
    public async Task workYoutuber()
    {
        var dmChannel = await Context.User.GetOrCreateDMChannelAsync();
        await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Enter the video title: ");
    }
```

How would I go about getting the next message? I know I can do:

```
public async Task workYoutuber([Remainder] string echo)
{
   await ReplyAsync(echo);
}
```

The problem with that is you have to enter it in with the command and I cant do that because the user does not know the question.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Use https://github.com/foxbot/Discord.Addons.Interactive -- there's a nuget package

Comment: Ive been suggested that before and I installed it, I couldnt find anything on how to use it (the methods) though

Comment: There is a sample project included in the github repo

Comment: I still don't get how I detect if a user has replied a specific thing after the command has been initiated.

Comment: It's [clearly shows](https://github.com/foxbot/Discord.Addons.Interactive/blob/master/SampleApp/Modules/SampleModule.cs#L23) in the [sample app](https://github.com/foxbot/Discord.Addons.Interactive/tree/master/SampleApp). It asks a question, waits for the answer, and uses the response.

Comment: Turns out I looked at the wrong one :/

Comment: When I change the module base to InteractiveBase it says it could not be found and pretty much all my other commands broke

Comment: Can you join the [Discord API](https://discord.gg/discord-api) server and ask in the `dotnet_discord-net` channel. Did you include the necessary `using`?

Comment: I used using Discord.Addons.InteractiveCommands;

Comment: no, just do `using Discord.Addons.Interactive;`.... Actually, InteractiveCommands? You may have installed the wrong package. That's deprecated.

Comment: I did that and I got an error saying the type or namespace interactive does not exist in the namespace discord.addons

Comment: Like I said, you probably installed the wrong one.